# What is this? Could this help aid in creating an electromagnetic field

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics

[image: this]

out of a Carvin Dcm1500 amp, and I was wondering if you guys could maybe tell me what it is, what it does, and what the connectors do?

Thank you!

Comment: It’s a power line AC transformer with multiple secondary windings.

Comment: OK, I change my vote. Vote to close because the question shows insufficient prior research.

Comment: the black connector is for the primary winding (AC power cord) .... the white connector are the secondary windings .... measure resistance between the different colors (**WITHOUT POWER CONNECTED**) .... that will tell you which wires are the separate windings ..... then plug into power and measure output voltages at individual windings

Comment: from the picture it looks like you have 5 secondaries `brown`, `red`, `yellow`, `green`and `violet` .... also looks like two of the wires go to a single pin  (brown/yellow ... hard to tell) .... that would make the pin with the two wires a `center tap` for a secondary winding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ordinary AC-AC toroidal transformer, which is frequently used in audio equipment, in power supply, due to its exceptionally low parasitic external fields, which helps to minimize "hum" in amplifiers. It likely has two secondary windings, one for power stage (thick copper wires), and another for +-15 V (typical) supply for pre-amplifier stages. Not sure though if it can help to create any electromagnetic field, all fields are confined within internal transformer core.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to tell me what each connector does? I'ma true and look it up.

Comment: @Wofo, you have a switch and clips, which likely are for primary connection to AC mains. Which voltage? Depends on your country of residence. Once powered, you can use DMM (in AC mode) to determine voltage of secondary windings. Check schematics for audio amplifiers, on repair DIY sites, it will give you many clues.

Comment: @Wofo these parts are often specific to the type of device they're found in, that means you'll have to work out the connector yourself.

Comment: @immibis ok cool thanks, I might just separate the magnetic wire out and make my own coil.

Comment: @Wofo chill and respect your elders, you made a mistake and actually did not even check youtube which my grand-daughter of 8 can do.  The transformer wire colors may match up on bottom right of schematics given here https://carvinaudio.com/pages/power-amplifier-schematic  They are usually custom. and if a replacement was needed hard to find except from websites like carvin.  This is not something you can make.  (without lots of skill)

Comment: The transformer will not contain any "magnetic wire" (whatever that may be).  It will be wound with copper wire around an iron core.

Comment: @PeterBennett, we probably shouldn't pick up on the kid. In American language they call it "magnet wire", probably because electromagents are made using this kind of enamel-coated wire. I was confused too first time.

Comment: @AliChen: I do know the term "magnet wire" but for some reason didn't associate it with the OP's "mangetic wire".